# Why generic type with wildcard works with instanceOf operator

Tags: java

```
class Gen<T>
{
T val;
Gen(T o)
{
val=o;
}
T getOb()
{
return val;
}
}
```

If we write following to test the above class

```
Gen<String> a=new Gen<String>();

if(a instanceOf Gen<?>) // this compiles
{

}

if(a instanceOf Gen<String>) // this doesn't compile.
{
}
```

So why first statement gets successfully compiled and second statement doesn't?

Please help me in understanding this?

Comment: Judging by the frequency of questions you post you spend no time researching the answers to your questions on your own. And the quality of your questions is deteriorating, the only valid lines of your "test" are the ones containing only `}` or `{`, all other lines contain errors.

Comment: @luk2302, I didn't get you, what is the meaning of your questions is deteriorating, the only valid lines of your "Test" are the ones containing only } or {, all other lines contain errors. If you have any java compiler with you , just run the above program.

Comment: you only define a constructor with a `T` parameter but call the constructor without a parameter. And `instanceOf` is invalid, `instanceof` is the correct format.

Comment: Ok so you could have said that in your comment. But nevertheless thanks for that. If I am posting any question here, it means I have done the research on my part, then only I am posting the question. Making such comments doesn't suit the person of your reputation.

Comment: The fact that out of your last 7 questions four are closed as duplicate and only one of them has a positive score begs to differ. I'm just trying to help: do more research and improve your question quality please. You even risk a https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans if you continue without change.